# How to calculate match percentage of 2 lists in python, for which A will not change and B will change dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2 lists which needs to find match percentage.

```
A = ['Apple','Apricots','Avocados','Bananas','Cherries','Dragon Fruit','Grapes','Guava','Jackfruit','Kiwi','Lychee','Mango','Melon','Oranges','Pomegranate','Pineapple','Raspberries','Strawberries','Watermelon','Star Fruit']

B = ['Apple','Apricots','Avocados','Bananas','Cherries','Dragon Fruit','Grapes','Guava','Jackfruit','Kiwi','Lychee','Mango','Melon','Oranges','Pomegranate','Pineapple']
```

I have written code like this to find the percentage of words for A.

```
print(f"Count of A: {len(A)}")
print(f'Count of B: {len(B)}')
d = len(A)+len(B)
print(f"Match Percentage: {round(100-((len(A)-len(B))/d*100), 2)}%")
```

Output as:

```
Count of A: 20
Count of B: 16
Match Percentage: 88.89%
```

Here A will not change, and B will change dynamically.

Ideally percentage looks like correct but Is this the right way to find the match percentage for list A with list B?

If this way of approach is not correct, can anyone help me with alternate approach?

Comment: If B is ensured to be a subset of A, then this is totally valid approach! However if not, you can count for each element in B, if it is in A using `for element in B: if element in A: counter += 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do the trick:

```
len(set(list_1).intersection(list_2)) / max(len(set(list_1)),len(set(list_2)))
```

Practically you get the length of their intersection and divide it to the `max` of `len(list_1), len(list_2)`. In this way you do not even care for which of the list gets dynamically changed.

The `set()` operation in the denominator is to ensure the elimination of possible duplicates.

Comment: I get the answer of 0.8, how do i get more precise percentage of it like decimal values too?

Comment: decimal_result = float("{0:.4f}".format(result)), where result is the intersection result

Comment: Still not getting the decimal values, when I increase a list by 1 value, then the percentage is increasing 5%. 
Example:1 Output
`
Count of A: 20
Count of B: 16
0.8
`
Example: 2 output
`
Count of A: 20
Count of B: 17
0.85
`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) package which is used for string matching.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not getting the expected result. This fuzzywuzzy will only work for string but not for list of string and I need match percentage of 2 lists.

Comment: You can convert the lists to string or this is not an option?

Comment: I converted that but no use.

Comment: I have just tested it and it is working on my end:

fuzz.ratio(str(A), str(B)) --> the result is -->
86

I have also installed python-Levenshtein for better perfomance